# elasticsearch compression and performance for front end

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, splunk, fluentd, kibana

Sorry in advance if it sounds very naive.
I started working with Elastic Search, I have about 10GB data coming in that i wanted to store in Elastic Search everyday, I read Elastic search does compression to 5% of original data. 
I have set up dashboard that is running based on data from Elastic Search but I am not sure if compression ratio is too high does it affect performance with searching and hence my dashboard doesn't show time based comparisons effectively.

Please feel free to ask if my question is not clear?
I do want to know how much is ES compression usually like I want to see example, and when we have Elastic Search instance how much maximum space do we ideally use it to store?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact benchmarking for any of these. As you can test and benchmark yourself.

You can get some Information from here.

[elasticsearch-compression-benchmark](http://www.robinverlangen.nl/index/view/50597e5876ad1-6e7e5f/elasticsearch-compression-benchmark.html)

Yes compression will make search slower.

There is no upper limit to storage, but it will keep on making elasticsearch slower as there will be more data to browse through.